# Issue setting active class with jquery, nodejs, express, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I have a express generator, node js application. I'm using bootstrap and jade  and having problems with setting the active state of the navigation bar.

I have been trying to use some jquery but when I click the nav bar the active state changes and then quickly changes back (it's not persistent). Any ideas what I am missing here? Thanks!

Here is my `layout.jade`

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
  body
    .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top(role='navigation')
      .container
        .navbar-header
          button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
          a.navbar-brand(href='/') Home
        .collapse.navbar-collapse
          ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li
              a(href='/about') About
            if user
              li
                a(href='/table') Table
              li
                a(href='/logout') Logout
            else
              li
                a(href='/login') Login
              li
                a(href='/signup') Signup
      block content

      script(src='//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')
      script(src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')
      script(type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/index.js')
```

And here is `/javascripts/index.js`

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
  $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That actually works, you get a page navigation which causes in a page refresh and active class gets removed. instead you can try adding class when the dom is ready:

```js
$(function() {

  var page = window.location.pathname;

  $('.nav li').filter(function(){
     return $(this).find('a').attr('href').indexOf(page) !== -1
  }).addClass('active');

  $(".nav a").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

or without filter you can replace that with:

```
$('.nav li').find('a[href="'+ page +'"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks!
I now understand that a page refresh stops the jQuery from persisting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not persistent because the page reloads each times you click on a navbar item. The jQuery method would be perfect if you loaded your pages content with Ajax, without reloading the entire page.

In your case, you can do it directly using Jade. You can set a variable (e.g. `active`) that will contain the ID, name or slug of the active section, and then run a check on the template, and assign the `active` class accordingly:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li(class=active == 'about' ? 'active' : '')
        a(href='/about') About
```

Comment: HI @Nikkow 
Thanks for the speedy response.
I removed the jQuery completely and change my jade.layout with this code:

ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li(class=active == 'about' ? 'active' : '')
              a(href='/about') About
            if user
              li(class=active == 'table' ? 'active' : '')
                a(href='/table') Table
              li(class=active == 'logout' ? 'active' : '')
                a(href='/logout') Logout

But nothing is getting set to active. Did I miss something important in your answer? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, you must set the variable on the rendering method on the NodeJS side: `res.render('template', { active: 'table'});`

Comment: Thanks so much! Amazing help!!!! :-)
I'm also going to look into AJAX, do you think this is a better solution in general???